# how can i pass the passphrase from nmcli while connecting a encrypted network in linux?

Tags: linux, networking, gnome

When i try to connect to a encrypted network using command line tool nmcli, it prompts for a passphrase with a popup. Instead of manually entering the passphrase in the popup, i would like to pass the passphrase directly from the command line. Is it possible to do that? If so, do you mind suggesting me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network manager version 0.9.6 solves this issue.